# Классы и проблемы

Tags: c++

Вроде бы простое задание, но выдает ошибку:

> non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member.

Как с ней бороться?

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

class Time
{
private:
    int hours, minutes, seconds;
public:
    Time();
    Time(int, int, int);
    int getHours()const;
    int getMinutes()const;
    int getSeconds()const;

    void setHours(int);
    void setMinutes(int);
    void setSeconds(int);
    void set(int, int, int);
    void print();
};

Time::Time(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
{
    set(hours, minutes, seconds);
}

Time::Time()
{
    hours = 0;
    minutes = 0;
    seconds = 0;
}

void Time::setHours(int hours)
{
    if (hours > -1 && hours < 24)
        this->hours = hours;
    else
        this->hours = 0;
}
int Time::getHours()const
{
    return hours;
}

void Time::setMinutes(int mminutes)
{
    if (mminutes > -1 && mminutes < 60)
        this->minutes = mminutes;
    else
        this->minutes = 0;
}
int Time::getMinutes()const
{
    return minutes;
}

void Time::setSeconds(int seconds)
{
    if (seconds > -1 && seconds < 60)
        this->seconds = seconds;
    else
        this->seconds = 0;
}
int Time::getSeconds()const
{
    return seconds;
}

void Time::set(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
{
    setHours(hours);
    setMinutes(minutes);
    setSeconds(seconds);
}

void Time::print()
{
    cout << hours << ":" << minutes << ":" << seconds;
}

int main()
{
    srand(GetTickCount());
    Time time;
    time.setHours(12);
    time.setMinutes(42);
    time.setSeconds(54);

    time.print;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А в какой строке ошибка? И приведите сообщение об ошибке полностью, должно быть что-то ещё по идее.

Comment: @Vadim Time time = new Time(); попробуй.

Comment: @Bangerok: Не откомпилируется, это же не Java.

Comment: @VladD здесь тоже так можно. Ждем ответа от автора.

Comment: @Bangerok, нет, так нельзя. Можно так: `Time *time = new Time();`, только тогда вместо точки будет стрелочка.

Comment: @maestro вот я только сейчас понял, что звездочек пропустил, но ничего, проблема все равно не в этом вроде все таки.

Answer (score 6):

print функция, это как минимум 
https://ideone.com/tuj5pZ

```
int main()
{

    Time time;
    time.setHours(12);
    time.setMinutes(42);
    time.setSeconds(54);

    time.print(); //<------
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что не так с print. Разъясни, пожалуйста.

Comment: void Time::print()
{
    cout << hours << ":" << minutes << ":" << seconds;
}
Так правильно: time.print();